# TopLink - Where are the JPA classes

Tags: java, jpa, toplink

Does Oracle TopLink not include the JPA classes?

I am trying to create a JPA/TopLink project. I have [downloaded the latest version of the TopLink jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/downloads/index.html) (12c 12.1.2) and made sure to include it in the classpath.

The problem is that I cannot seem to find any of the *javax.persistence.** classes like Entity, Column etc. I though that all implementations of JPA such as TopLink, Hibernate etc would include those classes. Is that not true? How else should I get this JPA/Toplink project to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/documentation/toplinkdatasheet1212-1973510.pdf) article, Toplink 12.1.2 is built off of EclipseLink and supplies extra goodies such as support for RESTful services, meaning the `javax.persistence.*` packages are contained within the `eclipselink.jar` file. This file should exist within the `jlib` folder of the `toplink.zip` download.

Comment: Aaron, Thanks for the answer. After reading this, I copied the zip version and the eclipselink.jar does have the javax.persistence package (I had got the self-installer before). However, the package does not have any of the annotation types that were there in the auto-generated code -  Entity,  Id,  Column etc. Where should i be looking?

Comment: There should be a file in the `modules` directory within the compressed file called `javax.persistence_2.0.jar` that contains the implementation of Entity, Id, Column, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your `javax.*` classes in the jars supplied with any Java EE compliant server (you can find the jar somewhere in the lib folder usually).  If you use maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the jar directly (version 7):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0

Put it on your relevant classpath and everything should work (im not sure about toplink, you might need version 6 of API - which can be also found in maven repositories).